# Grails and Icepush. Any good starting point?

Tags: grails, collaboration, icepush

I'm planning to build a more or less simple collaborative web application allowing users
to be part in different simultanous proccesses by switching through them.

I thought I give Icepush a try using it as a grails plugin (I have some experience using grails).

However, documentation on using it together with grails seems to be rare so my question is:

Do you know any good tutorial / Demo (despite the official chat demo) or anything else that could help me in the beginning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additionaly:If you know a better/easier approach for my project it's more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only source of information additional to the official demo is their chat area. Anyways, IcePush has very little working examples even there. It changes so fast, that no demo is never 100% uptodate. Chat and info on [their pages](http://www.icepush.org/).

Being made that on Vaadin, I can say it is not the easiest task I have faced.